# Add CKEditor widget (footnotes) from external addon

Tags: 8, wysiwyg, plugins

I want to add [CKEditor footnotes addon](https://github.com/andykirk/CKEditorFootnotes) to a Drupal 8 toolbar.

The plugin seems to load as I can add the button when configuring the input format  and I see `CKEDITOR.plugins.externals.footnotes` is defined and pointing to my plugin file. However the button does not show in the toolbar. No errors or warnings in the console.

This is my `/modules/custom/ckeditorfootnotes/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/CKEditorFootnotes.php`

```
class CKEditorFootnotes extends CKEditorPluginBase implements CKEditorPluginInterface, CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface {

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginInterface::getFile().
   */
  function getFile() {
    return drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditorfootnotes') . '/js/footnotes/plugin.js';
  }

  /**
   * Implements \Drupal\ckeditor\Plugin\CKEditorPluginButtonsInterface::getButtons().
   */
  function getButtons() {
    return array(
      'CKEditorFootnotes' => array(
        'label' => t('Footnotes'),
        'image' => drupal_get_path('module', 'ckeditorfootnotes') . '/js/footnotes/icons/footnotes.png'
      )
    );
  }
```

This is  filter.format.basic_html

```
    uuid: b47ec9da-02dc-420c-8100-c2127d8e5012
    langcode: ca
    status: true
    dependencies:
      module:
        - editor
    name: 'HTML bàsic'
    format: basic_html
    weight: 0
    filters:
      filter_html:
        id: filter_html
        provider: filter
        status: false
        weight: -10
        settings:
          allowed_html: '<a href hreflang target> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote cite> <code> <ul type> <ol start type> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd> <h2 id> <h3 id> <h4 id> <h5 id> <h6 id> <p> <br> <span> <img src alt height width data-entity-type data-entity-uuid data-align data-caption> <s> <table> <caption> <tbody> <thead> <tfoot> <th> <td> <tr> <sub> <sup> <section>'
          filter_html_help: false
          filter_html_nofollow: false
      filter_align:
        id: filter_align
        provider: filter
        status: true
        weight: 7
        settings: {  }
      filter_caption:
        id: filter_caption
        provider: filter
        status: true
        weight: 8
        settings: {  }
      filter_html_image_secure:
        id: filter_html_image_secure
        provider: filter
        status: true
        weight: 9
        settings: {  }
      editor_file_reference:
        id: editor_file_reference
        provider: editor
        status: true
        weight: 11
        settings: {  }
```

And finally `editor.editor.basic_html`

```
uuid: 175d53b1-06a9-4aca-9755-85595f23633b
langcode: ca
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - filter.format.basic_html
  module:
    - ckeditor
    - editor_file
third_party_settings:
  editor_file:
    status: true
    scheme: public
    directory: inline-files
    extensions: txt
format: basic_html
editor: ckeditor
settings:
  toolbar:
    rows:
      -
        -
          [... several groups ...]
        -
          name: Media
          items:
            - CKEditorFootnotes
            - DrupalFile
            - Blockquote
            - DrupalImage
            - Table
        -
          [... more groups ...]
  plugins:
    stylescombo:
      styles: ''
image_upload:
  status: true
  scheme: public
  directory: inline-images
  max_size: ''
  max_dimensions:
    width: null
    height: null
```

Comment: I am still struggling with this. I have tried to implement the simplebox ckeditor tutorial as a Drupal module and I have hit the same roadblock. No errors whatsoever but the button is not showing. It does show on the admin pages though: https://github.com/esclapes/editor_simplebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you need to call `editor.ui.addButton()` to get the buttons to show.

It seems to me that it is not usually needed in *vanilla* CKEditor development, because it is not included neither in the tutorials nor in the ckeditorfootnotes plugin. However, most of the current Drupal 8 CKEditor modules do include it in the plugin source.

For the simplebox plugin it would read like this, here `command` is the name of the defined widget.

```
editor.ui.addButton('SimpleBox', {
    label: Drupal.t('SimpleBox'),
    command: 'simplebox',
    icon: this.path + 'icons/simplebox.png'
});
```